# Can a property of an Abstract Class be access outside the class?

Tags: php, properties, abstract-class

Is is possible to access a variable in a PHP abstract class, i.e.

```
abstract class Settings
{
    public $application = array
    (
        'Name' => 'MyApp',
        'Version' => '1.0.0',
        'Date' => 'June 1, 2017'
    )
}

echo Settings::application ['Name'];   // doesn't work
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted for asking a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the variable [*static*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), as long as it doesn't need to allow differentiation across instances (i.e. instance variable):

```
<?php
// example code

abstract class Settings
{
    public static $application = array
    (
        'Name' => 'MyApp',
        'Version' => '1.0.0',
        'Date' => 'June 1, 2017'
    );
}

echo Settings::$application ['Name'];
```

Run it in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/KeiziYIdtHHzfAeC).

Though your original access of `application` was similar to that of a constant. use `const` to declare a [Class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
abstract class Settings
{
    const application = array
    (
        'Name' => 'MyApp',
        'Version' => '1.0.0',
        'Date' => 'June 1, 2017'
    );
}

echo Settings::application ['Name'];
```

Run it in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/RO0aULTdZeCpmckz).

Comment: Thanks. I like the 2nd solution better. I'm using this to replace XML files for storing web app settings. I could use a regular class, but I don't want to instantiate it just to retrieve variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Abstract Classes can not be directly instantiated as they rely on
>   child classes to fully implement the functionality.

So if you want to check your variable I would make new class and inherit from your Settings class. **You will have to use it with inheritance anyway.**

```
class MySettings extends Settings
{
  ....
}

$mySettings = new MySettings();
echo $mySettings->application['Name'];
```

More about abstract classes http://culttt.com/2014/03/26/abstract-classes/

Comment: [That would lead to a parse error](https://www.tehplayground.com/cmJXpoZkpD5oQBuU)...

Comment: Alright that looks better, though there is a [typo on the property name now](https://www.tehplayground.com/JuvPO4uUv8NRrerD)

Comment: Edited and fixed :)